# Python: replace NULLs with Average

Tags: python, null, mean, fillna

I am newbie in Python and I need your expert help.
I have a table with multiple rows for the same games. But in column "rating" rows some cells for this or that game are empty and some are not.
Question: how do I fill the missing values in the column with average ratings for the same game?

Please see the table structure in the picture below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uF9IC.png)

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to fill the values using average of groups in 'Name' , you can use a combination of [`pandas groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), [`pandas apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), and [`pandas fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

```
>>>df['Rating_score']=df.groupby('Name')['Rating_score'].apply(lambda x:x.fillna(x.mean()))
>>>df
  
    Name     Genere  Rating_score
0  Game1  Adventure          65.0
1  Game1  Adventure          70.0
2  Game1  Adventure          67.5
3  Game2     Racing          59.0
4  Game2     Racing          61.5
5  Game2     Racing          64.0
6  Game3   Shooting          71.0
7  Game3   Shooting          71.0
```

Comment: Hi Shijith! Thank you for your help, your approach worked like a charm. Have a great day :)